# How to use font file as a blob and use in css

Tags: html, css, font-face

i am trying to use a font file as a blob format and used in css, is it correct way or always font file can use in url way only?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "sample";
    src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAASA..
}
body{
    font-family: sample;font-size: 20px;
  }
```

i convert the font file into blob format and use in src. but not rendering in browser is there any missing , please suggest how to use.